# Wiring LEDs to a 120 VAC wall outlet

Tags: power-supply, led, mains

I have a water pump that is powered from a 120 VAC wall outlet, which will be used to move water in a makeshift fountain I am assembling. I want to power some 6 VDC LEDs from the same plug to give it some lighting effects  but I don't want to accidentally cut off the power to the small water pump.

I have seen various posts about getting a transformer or capacitors to drive the LEDs, but I can't quite get my head around how to implement any of these solutions. I know I can use batteries to drive the LEDs, but if I have to plug the pump in anyway, I would prefer to power the entire fountain and LEDs from one plug.

Comment: It would help to have some idea about the number and type of LEDs you are considering. These are 6 V LEDs, I gather. Can you provide a link to them? And some kind of "no more than X many of them" answer? (Also, doesn't the supplier of these LEDs also provide a plug-in supply you can use?)

Comment: The LEDs are actually from some keychain led Lights that are powered from button cell batteries. No more than 5 Leds will be used, and yes they are 6V. I bought some blacklight LED kechains from amazon, ill post the amazon link. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00NOFMJKW/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Interesting. I got some similar devices quite some time back. As I recall, mine used ONE CR2032. Your link definitely says they use two CR2016. However, you need to realize that the CR2016 ***physically cannot*** deliver much current. So it is self-limiting. When you pull an LED out, is there a resistor present? Or are the leads directly in contact with the battery pair when turned on? I think you may need to test one of these with a power supply that is capable of a LOT of current and tell us what happens if you supply 6 V. My guess is they burn up fast.

Comment: There are no resistors, the leads are connected directly to the button cell batteries. but since they will be on for a prolonged period of time, Batteries aren't really an option for this project. I am sure there is some kind of converter I can wire to wall plug in the water pump to drive these leds, but I dont know what I am looking for which is my main problem.

Comment: A problem for us telling you what to do is that we don't have the specifications for those LEDs. And knowing that they were used with CR2016's doesn't help, because those are very WEAK sources. If you build/buy a mains-derived DC power supply, it will NOT be similarly weak. So you are changing situations and we don't know what your LED actually requires in this new situation. You can do some tests and collect some info. Do you have a voltmeter? Any resistors? Any kind of mains-derived DC supply to try out for a test? Can you turn it on and then measure the battery voltage while it is still on?

Comment: I have a voltmeter. I dont have a dc supply because I didnt know what to look for. I dont have resistors either because I was hoping to get recommendations here before I bought them. I also am not sure how to wire an AC to DC supply directly from a cable that plugs into a wall outlet. I have experience wiring electronics and using power supplies, I am just hoping for some advice.

Comment: Turn the light on (squeeze or whatever) and then, while the light is on, use the voltmeter and measure the voltage across the LED itself. Touch the leads of the voltmeter to the leads of the LED while it is on with the battery. Report the reading.

Comment: Will do. I will need to wait until tomorrow though since the LEDs were delayed in shipping. I appreciate the help. This may sound like a novice question, but if I wire the wall plug to a 120VAC to 12VDC transformer as well as keeping it connected to the pump, will current still flow to the pump as well as the LEDs? or will it only take the path of least resistance?

Comment: I don't think there will be a problem running your pump AND ALSO the LEDs. The LEDs will be almost not even noticed. A 12.6 VAC secondary transformer won't harm the pump, either. (At least, not unless you are buying something truly huge that weighs 50 lbs or something.) Yeah, you are overthinking this. All you want is the pump to work (I'm assuming it connects directly to your mains AC) and for a safe voltage and circuit for the LEDs -- and a transformer is probably a good idea for the isolation it offers you in this wet environment. But let's see what readings you get.

Comment: Great, thats what I was hoping to hear. Its been a while since I dis any personal projects like this so I appreciate the advice and will report back with the readings I get when the LEDS come in

Comment: @Whit3rd Their may be an unfortunate confusion possible with your wording. The US NEC (who cares about home electrical fire risks) has an "NEC Class 2 power supply" which is very different in purpose and meaning than it would be for an "IEC Class II power supply." I suspect you are talking about "IEC Class II" and not "NEC Class 2". The ones with the double square marking, right?

Comment: Is the pump 120VAC or 12VDC?

Comment: @jonk Yeah, I was sloppy with that.   How about this: Interconnecting 120VAC (for the pump) and low-voltage DC (for the LEDs) usually means a class II "double insulated"  safe-to-touch low voltage power supply adapter. Buy one.

Comment: A 6VDC AC-DC adapter, the type for electronic devices, would do the job.  You may want to connect or solder the output to larger gauge wires if the the adapter / power supply  is more than several meters away from the fountain.

Answer (score 1):

Most common LEDs operate at about 20mA

eg: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1793

3.4V forwards voltage so from a 5V "USB-shaped" supply you'd need to drop 1.6V - ar 20mA that's 80 ohms.  so use a 82 ohm resistor (0.05W or larger) for each LED

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwz8FE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: He said "*No more than 5 Leds will be used*." Your circuit is wrong!! ;) Oh my gosh!

Comment: hah! oops! edit!

Comment: He makes no mention of USB supply

Comment: he says "a transformer" - usb-chargers are cheap and convenient

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a capacitive power supply. But ONLY if the circuitry is not in contact with the water. It is a rather simple circuit that drops AC voltage to a lower DC level by way of capacitive reactance. Here is a link to the Wikipedia page for more information:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_power_supply

This circuit should work relatively well for low power circuits, and it is used in some cheaper consumer electronics which are powered from mains. But before you use this circuit, be warned that the output is NOT isolated from the mains power lines as it would be with a transformer! Therefore, it is extremely important that this circuit is ONLY used where it is impossible (or highly unlikely) for the user to come into contact with any parts of the circuit physically. Electric shock may result if this precaution is not followed. Needless to say, you should probably not use this circuit for larger loads.

Comment: a non-isolated supply is not the the sort of thing I'd recommend anyone use around water, but yeah if it can be insulated and kept dry, it's a candidate.

Comment: I would not recommend that either. Moreover it's for really low power applications. I don't downvote the answer because you still warned about the danger.

Comment: Several failure modes of capacitive power supplies result in hazardous voltages being exposed.  The awful power factor is possibly excusable but really that kind of circuit went out of favour in the 1970s, or at least should have.